# Using NGINX server to deploy a Meteor App from Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.2 instance receive Module Error

Tags: heroku, nginx, amazon-ec2, node-modules

I am attempting to deploy my first web application (a version of Telescope from the MeteorJS framework) via Heroku to a custom subdomain from a Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.2 instance. I am following along with this tutorial - http://satishgandham.com/2013/12/a-complete-guide-to-install-production-ready-telescope-on-your-own-server/ - but once I attempt to run Telescope using `PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3000/Telescope ROOT_URL=http://ec2-54-193-42-229.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com node client/main.js`, I receive this error message: `Error: Cannot find module '/home/ec2-user/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/client/main.js'`

What I have attempted to do to solve this problem is performed `cp || mv` on the file `main.js` which is originally located in the `~/Telescope/client` directory over to `/home/ec2-user/bundle/programs/server` directory and even '/home/ec2-`user/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers` but I cannot seem to separate `main.js` from the `/client` directory. I am not sure if that is the issue or if there is some other underlying problem but I want to find a work around to using a proxy server at this point. I thought that moving the `main.js` file out of the `/client` directory was sufficient but apparently not.  I am not sure it is imperative for my purposes to continue attempting to use a proxy but if there is a fix, I would not mind learning about it.

Or if any one could direct me on how this - https://github.com/aldeed/deploymeteor/ - could be a potential work-around to using an NGINX server proxy your help would be much appreciated.

[image: Error]

Comment: Edited the image in for you  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are not running the command from your home folder.

You were at bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers.

Either use absolute path for client/main.js, or cd to ~

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3000/Telescope ROOT_URL=http://ec2-54-193-42-229.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com node client/main.js
```

PS: It will be helpful for others if you asked the question on the post itself, instead of here